# Why the numbers are not resolved in IF condition in Perl without quotes

Tags: perl, datetime

I have a script which will do certain set of operation based on the `time` in `IF` condition. So basically `IF` will look for the Current Time which is Hour and Minutes.

Here is the script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $TIME = `date '+%H%M'`;
chomp $TIME;

print $TIME."\n";

if (( $TIME > 0100) && ($TIME < 0300)){
        print "1st IF\n";
} elsif (( $TIME > 0300) && ($TIME < 0500)){
        print "2nd IF\n";
} else {
        print "Default IF\n";
}
```

Lets say now the time is `0130` and it suppose to print `1st IF`. But its printing `Default IF`.
Similarly when the time is `0430` and it suppose to print `2nd IF`. But its printing `Default IF`.

But when I enclose the time value in double quotes `""` it works. Like below -

```
if (( $TIME > "0100") && ($TIME < "0300")){
```

Do the `$TIME` is resolving as a string ? I was thinking the `$TIME` would have numbers and it doesn't require quotes.

Comment: A number literal starting with a zero is interpreted as an octal number

Comment: [perlnumber](http://p3rl.org/perlnumber)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can find in [perlnumber](http://p3rl.org/perlnumber), literal numbers starting with zeros are interpreted as octal numbers. `0100` is therefore `64` and `0300` is 192.

When numifying a string, leading zeros are ignored.

See also [Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece) on how to handle time in Perl without the need to shell out.

```
use Time::Piece;
my $time = localtime->strftime('%H%M');
```

Answer (score 4):

[Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) has been a standard part of the Perl distribution since Perl 5.10 (in 2002). If you use the right tool for the job, then things get a lot easier :-)

```
use Time::Piece;

my $hour = localtime->hour;

if ($hour > 1 and $hour < 3) {
  # do something
} elsif ($hour > 3 and $hour < 5) {
  # do something else
} else {
  # do the default thing
}
```

**Update:** You don't even need to use Time::Piece. You can get the hour from [`localtime()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) easily enough.

```
my $hour = (localtime)[2];

# The rest of the code is the same as my previous example
```